# How can I deal with repeat teamkillers in BFBC2 Hardcore mode on PS3?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-bad-company-2

I've experienced that killing people in the own team becomes more and more common. Sometimes it's because they want to have the vehicle you're taking, sometimes I guess just for fun (I've even seen someone named "Teamkiller...") or as a revenge for being (possibly unintentionally) team-killed.

This is no fun at all and can turn the whole game around.

Losing a few points and having team kills in your record doesn't seem to scare many people off. For example, experienced players can easily compensate for -100 points for shooting a team mate before entering a helicopter, by then taking that helicopter and destroying tanks.

How can I remove teamkillers that are ruining a game from Battlefield Bad Company 2 Hardcore games?  How can I keep them from coming back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be harsh but you can get TK'ers [PSN accounts blocked](http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=1260)

Comment: Although I'd prefer some automatic mechanism, that's good to know - thanks!

Comment: No, that's not possible. PSN accounts can't be blocked for gameplay (or lack thereof)